# Apollo codegen:generate gives error "Generating query files with 'typescript' target"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have backend on Express with Apollo Graph.

In my client React app im do next:

```
apollo codegen:generate --excludes=node_modules/* --includes=**/*.tsx --target typescript --tagName gql --outputFlat generate
```

I wait for folder generated, but this command gives me next error:

```
Error: There are multiple definitions for the herewas operation. 
All operations in a project must have unique names. 
If generating types, only the types for the first definition 
found will be generated.at GraphQLClientProject.checkForDuplicateOperations 
(....\node_modules\apollo\node_modules\apollo-language-server\lib\project\base.js:129:31)
.........
.........
Generating query files with 'typescript' target
> Apollo does not support anonymous operations
```

Also i have apollo.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  client: {
    service: {
      url: "http://localhost:4000/graphql"
    }
  }
}
```

I do not understand where to dig, the code took from Google search

Answer (score 6):

> Apollo does not support anonymous operations

You should give your query/mutation operation a name :

This will work:

```
query SOME_NAME {
  users {
    age
  }
}
```

This will **NOT** work (note that query name is missing):

```
query {
  users {
    age
  }
}
```

Also you can check this thread:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling/issues/184

Answer (score 1):

*operation name* required.
Something like below, required the name.

```
query {
  users {
    name
  }
}
```